# how to use roslaunch having gazebo on verbose mode?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear all,

when you develop plugins in gazebo, you can get the verbose feedback by executing:

```
gazebo my_world.world --verbose
```

When we use roslaunch to launch the gazebo simulation, do you know a similar way to get verbose feedback?
I tried to find a simial input arg but I couldn't since debug means different thing.

(using gazebo7.8 and ros kinetic)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16560/how-to-use-roslaunch-having-gazebo-on-verbose-mode?/) by [Angelos](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3366/angelos/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2017-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can add `extra_gazebo_args:="--verbose"` to your roslaunch command.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Angelos](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3366/angelos/) on 2017-06-28**:
Thank you Louise!

**Comment by [Ruben](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2931/ruben/) on 2019-07-10**:
I've tested this parameter `extra_gazebo_args:="--verbose"` on `ROS Kinetic with Gazebo 7.15.0` but at the end `--verbose` is not passed to `gzserver`. Do we need a specific ROS or Gazebo version for that?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can use this :

```
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="verbose" value="true" />
</include>
```

---

Originally posted by [blevesque](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3192/blevesque/) with karma: 61 on 2017-06-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3